# How to terminate void function in c#?

Tags: c#

i have a trouble terminating a void function in C#, i tried to put all the function body in a try and created catch body to throw nothing but termination, my question Is this method the best to terminate void function, Or you have another better solution?

Code Below

```
public void funCall(string element, TreeNode tree){
        try
        {
            string[] constraintsOfFunction = { };
            try
            {
                constraintsOfFunction = splitter(symbol[element].Key.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errorHandler(3);
            }
            string paramsCount = constraintsOfFunction[0];
            foreach (var x in tree.Nodes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(paramsCount); i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(constraintsOfFunction[i]);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {   }

    }
```

Comment: would a simple `return` do the trick?

Comment: That is just an expensive goto. Try Daniels suggestion.

Comment: @DanielA.White it works! thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I exit from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625305/how-do-i-exit-from-a-function)

Comment: @ZeyadEtman now would be a great time to use google, do a simple search on `C# Basics Tutorial` there are tons of free online resources. I would start with learning the basics before coming here first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so by adding this line:

```
return;
```

For `foreach`, `for`, and `while` loops, you must use the following to exit the loop:

```
break;
```

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried a `finally{}` for the `try catch`? Ultimately, you just need to `return;`